# Proving a statement in the form $A \implies (B \implies C )$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Say I have a statement in the form

$$A \implies (B \implies C )$$

how can I prove it? Should I assume $A$ and $B$ and then try to prove $C$ from them ?

It seems that it could be the right thing because if $A = \bot $ then the statement is always true, so I assume $A$, now if $B = \bot$ then again I have an always true statement because $A$ is true and $B \implies C$ is true so I assume also $B$.

Is my reasoning right? Is there an intuitive explanation of this 'iterative' process?

Comment: Your iterative process is called Currying :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying#Logic

Comment: really interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may not be the most intuitive, but you can observe that this statement is equivalent to $(A \land B) \implies C$, either by truth table or natural deduction:

\begin{align}&\quad \ \ A \implies (B \implies C)\\
&\equiv\neg A \lor (\neg B \lor C) &\text{(Material Implication)}\\
&\equiv(\neg A \lor \neg B) \lor C &\text{(Associativity of $\lor$)}\\
&\equiv\neg(A \land B) \lor C &\text{(De Morgan's Law)}\\
&\equiv (A \land B) \implies C &\text{(Material Implication)}\\
\end{align}

so one can prove the statement is true by proving $C$ holds if both $A, B$ hold.

Comment: thanks (+1), I suspected that with some logic rules I could arrive at the statement, but as you said it's not the most intuitive way, it seems as logic is not so logical for me :P

Comment: I can't believe I actually forgot that this is the Rule of Exportation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exportation_(logic). The proof in Wikipedia is identical to mine.

Answer (score 4):

> Should I assume $A$ and $B$ and then try to prove $C$ from them?

Using a form of natural deduction, the key is to make two *separate* assumptions...

1. Assume $A$
2. Assume $B$
3. Prove $C$
4. Discharge assumption (2) to obtain $B\implies C$
5. Discharge assumption (1) to obtain $A\implies(B\implies C)$

Comment: Can you please clarify what does it mean discharging an assumption?

Comment: If you assume $P$ and are able to prove $Q$ without subsequently introducing other assumptions, then we can conclude that $P \implies Q$. This process is called "discharging assumption $P$." Note that once an assumption is discharged in a proof, it and any statements that followed it are is effectively "deactivated" and can no longer be used in the proof. Also, you can only discharge the LAST occurring active assumption.

Comment: @Tortar Various presentations of natural deduction systems (eg "Fitch Style") will use some form of indentation to indicate the *context* under which its raised assumption is active. An inference using a rule "discharging the assumption" usually follows immediately after closing this; in this case the rule will be named "conditional introduction", "implication introduction", or similar, because that is basically what it does.$$\small\def\fitch#1#2{~~~~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}\fitch{}{\fitch{A}{\fitch{B}{~\vdots~\textsf{(some valid derivation)}\\C}\\B\to C}\\A\to(B\to C)}$$